Chrome Android scales text size from the third paragraph
I have a problem with Chrome Android and it is that it greatly scales the size of the text starting from the third paragraph without respecting the indicated font size (px, em, rem, %, etc.). It only happens with Chrome android and browsers based on it, in the desktop version of Chrome and in the rest of the browsers the font size is maintained or scales very little. Example:
Code for more than 2 rows:
<html>
<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div style="color:white; font-size:50px;">
      <p>Selected text size: 50px. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows. More than 2 rows.</p>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Code for less than 3 rows:
<html>
<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div style="color:white; font-size:50px;">
      <p>Selected text size: 50px. Less than 3 rows.</p>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>


For great clarity I hosted the code for both options here:
More than 2 rows:
https://ra2ven27.github.io/Prueba/index.html
Less then 3 rows:
https://ra2ven27.github.io/Prueba/index2.html
To see the differences must be accessed through chrome android.

Are you sure you don't have some styling in the css for #global12 I couldn't replicate the problem based on the code you provided.

I erased #global12 and it´s the same

I have added two links to the two options to see it better. It must be accessed through chrome android.

I'm not saying this is the cause, but what's the point of all the divs and redundant style definitions? Like defining the font size twice or having an outer div, then a middle div, then an inner div while neither really affects how the page is displayed.
Aside of that, have you tried setting the inner div as display: flex and flex-grow: 0? That should prevent any kind of resizing on it. You also should include <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the head of the file. I'm not saying either solves the problem, but they worth a try.

Also, I would delete the fixed width styling too, as that can be a source of problems. Mobile screens are recognized as 400-600 pixel wide by the browser. Since you set the width to fixed 1000px, maybe that causes some resizing when the browser renders the page.

I have simplified the code as much as possible and it is the same.
It must be a very simple thing because otherwise millions of web pages would have the same problem with that browser.

I tried your source code on my own site. Adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> to the <head> section makes the text sizing constant, regardless of the lines.
By the way, including this in the html head is pretty much the most fundamental thing you need to do when developing a site with mobile users in mind. This line tells the browser the basic scaling of the site.
This link from mdn web docs pretty well describes why it works that way.

This is the solution, thank you.
